# How do I make the Scroll Viewer scroll while resizing a UsercontrolView?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, scrollview, caliburn.micro

I have a view which is one amongst the mutiple views in the 'DataViewModels'. I have to make the scrollviewer visible and scroll when the UsercontrolView is resized. I tried adding the scrollviewer outside the Grid with a definite height, but it didn't scrolled as expected... I am amused what can be the right way to add a scrollviewer to the MySampleWindowView such that it is resolution independent.

Here's the code:

```
 <views:UserControlView x:Class="XYZ.DataViewModels.MySampleWindow.MySampleWindowView"
                        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:XYZ.Views"                     
                        d:DesignHeight="600"
                        d:DesignWidth="600">

 <UserControl.Resources />

   <Border BorderThickness="1"
                BorderBrush="Gray"
                x:Name="RootElement">

   <Grid Background="{DynamicResource DataViewColor}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <StackPanel Grid.Row = "0"/>
       <GroupBox   Grid.Row = "1"/>
       <GroupBox   Grid.Row = "2"/>
   </Grid>

   </Border>
</views:UserControlView>
```

Comment: Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: I don't want a scrollviewer of Fixed height.